# How can I use min() and max() on a same list

Tags: python

So I'm new in coding and I was trying to get the maximum and minimum number in a same list.

I tried to use `max(min(` and `max + min`

```
print(max + min(18, 20, 35, 285, 285.01, 300-1))
```

How can I get the 18 and 300-1 together? I got `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'int'`

Comment: You _really_ need to format the code here to show what you're using. I had a go and got lost. `max` is a built-in function so `max + min(18, 20, 35, 285, 285.01, 300-1)` cannot work, as the error says

Comment: Are you trying to refer *on the same pass*? Because that would be a very valid question. Otherwise, you can just do min(list) than max(list) separately

Comment: Sorry I didn't think formatting was that important, I'm new in this site too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call `max()` and `min()` on the list

```
l = [18,20,35,285,285.01,300-1]

print(min(l), max(l))
print(min(l) + max(l))
```

> (18, 299)
>
> 317

Answer (score 0):

You have to run each operation separately, e.g.:

```
myvalues = 18, 20, 35, 285, 285.01, 300-1
print(max(myvalues) + min(myvalues))
```

The only other way to do this is to sort it and pull out the first and last elements, e.g.:

```
minval, *_, maxval = sorted([18, 20, 35, 285, 285.01, 300-1])
print(maxval + minval)
```

but given sorting is `O(n log n)` work, where `min` and `max` are `O(n)`, it's usually best to just do two passes, one for `min`, one for `max`.

Comment: Thanks I'll use the first one which seems easier to understand